# jQuery trigger click event from iframe

Tags: jquery

Possible use `click` event from inside of `<iframe>` ?

```
<iframe src="page" height="320px"></iframe>
<a href="#" id="mylink" target="_blank">test</a>
```

So i succesfully changed `<a>` href from inside `<iframe>` using this code:

> window.parent.$('#mylink').attr("href", 'www.google.com');

But is it possible to trigger click event also ?

Thanks!

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/trigger-from-iframe-to-parent-window possibly relevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

`$('iframe').contents().find('a').trigger('click');`

But rememver [Cross origin policies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)